# Is there a way to convert Facebook post data into a Product on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Here's my question/idea.

I saw this being done by a Group on Facebook that provided support for their theme through a group page..

They required that all members post their support questions with a title like this: [ Title ]

So it got me thinking. Why would they be doing this, maybe they were somehow able to create a ticket in their support website or something...

So, I would like to see if someone out there can help me see its possible to generate a Product for Sale in an Auction Plugin that I have for WordPress.

Here's an Example post I'm trying to convert over to data for our site.

WYSIWYG: 
Name: Unknown Acan 4 head
Starting bid: 3 
Minimum bid increments: 3
End Time: Friday 10/26/18 at 8:00pm MST
Last honored bid: 7:59:59
Pick up location: Cottonwood Heights

So I'm thinking doing something like this:

```
[WYSIWYG] . <<< This will be Category
[Name] Unknown Acan 4 head <<< Product Name
[Starting bid] 3 <<< Starting Price
[Minimum bid increments] 3 <<< Min. Bid Increment
[End Time] Friday 10/26/18 at 8:00pm MST <<< End Time
[Pick up location] Cottonwood Heights <<< Shipping Option
```

Comment: so what is your question? did you try using the graph api already? stackoverflow is a platform for developers, you need to show what you have tried so far. we´re not doing all the work for you ;)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is just find out IF its possible..... I'm not asking for the code or anything like that....

Comment: finding out if something is possible would be your job as well, i´m afraid ;) - that is what developers do, they try stuff. if they get stuck, they go to stackoverflow. sorry, but that´s how it works, you are not really stuck with a problem, you did not even try. i hope that is understandable.